# Original paper of Gauss on his method of quadrature

Tags: mathematics

I tried to find Gauss's original paper on his method of quadrature, but in vain. Is it translated into English?

How about Legendre's paper?

Answer (score 4):

You can find a link to Gauss' 1815 paper on numerical quadrature, ``*Methodus nova integralium valores per approximationem inveniendi*'' [here](https://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k2412190.image).  I'm not aware of any translation of it into English.